# Realgcc: no disk on D: error

Tags: haskell

Just installed the last version of the Haskell platform, but when calling "ghci" from CMD, I get the following error: 
 
[image]

Searched over the web for solutions, but the best I found was [this](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/1798) post, which solution was reinstalling Windows. I do not want to reinstall right now, so, has anyone experienced this before? How can I fix?

Comment: does the same happen if you invoke winghc instead of calling ghci from the commandline?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/1798
says you could also remap the D: drive to another letter while they fix the issue